# How to debug Java and Perl code in Eclipse in same debug session?

Tags: java, eclipse, perl, debugging

### Setup:

I am working on a Java project which invokes some Perl scripts.

### Problem:

If I run the Perl script from terminal, it works fine. But when I invoke the same Perl script with same arguments from Java code, it fails. It is an extremely strange and annoying bug.

I am able to debug Perl in Eclipse using EPIC plugin. And of course, I can debug Java code. It would be helpful to debug Java and Perl code in the same debug session in Eclipse, so that I can see whats different happening when the script is invoked via Java code.

Not sure if this is even possible, but if anyone has any idea, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has some remote debugging capabilities, so you can get what you need, I think.  I don't use EPIC, so I don't know if you'll be able to do it all within Eclipse.

Set the environment variable named `PERLDB_OPTS` to have the value `RemotePort=<host>:<port>`.  Then, start Perl with the `-d` flag.  Instead of the debugger trying to interact with standard IO on the invoking terminal, it will attempt to connection to host:port.

Here's a Unix-y example.  I've got a Perl script `hello.pm` and two terminal windows open.

**First terminal**

```bash
$ nc -l 12345
```

That's started NetCat as a dumb server listening on port 12345.  If you don't have a server listening *before* Perl starts, it won't work.

**Second terminal**

```bash
$ export PERLDB_OPTS=RemotePort=localhost:12345     # set the env variable
$ perl -d hello.pm
```

Now the script is running.  Back on the first terminal, I see

**First terminal**

```bash
main::(hello.pm:1): print "hello\n";
  DB<1>
```

I'm in the Perl debugger and ready to go!

---

I know that at least the Komodo IDE has support for remote debugging, and there's a Perl Monks post on [doing it with Emacs](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=629411), so you can get something more than the command line even if it's not Eclipse.  Good bug hunting!

Answer (score 0):

> If I run the Perl script from terminal, it works fine. But when I invoke the same Perl script with same arguments from Java code, it fails.

I suggest that you check that you are running the same version of Perl in the two "contexts"; i.e. when the Perl app is run from the command line and from Java.

If that's not the problem, check the environment variables.

---

The other approach to solving this problem would be to focus on why the program is going wrong, not on how / why the contexts are different.  Look at the evidence that you have, and look at ways to gather more evidence ...

---

The potential problem with trying to do this using a Perl a debugger (in an IDE or stand-alone) is that you are actually running Perl in third "context" which might be different from either or both of the existing ones.

Using a debugger may work ... or it may leave you even more confused.